# Are there any good books on writing commercial quality software?

Tags: c#, .net

My background has been generally new technology demonstrators, which, well... demonstrate the latest technology and how it can be of use to a clients company. They use it for internal demos etc.

Now my career has shiffed course a bit more into actual products, in particular software which runs in locations like museums as interactive pieces.

Clearly, although the technology demonstrators had to be well coded etc, there wasn't as much emphasis as there is on my current work, which has to work, be highly configurable, probably multi-ligual and run constantly, without restarts.

So my question is, now that I'm trying to up my coding quality and write more commercial applications, are there any books which discuss issues surrounding high quality commercial software?

I currently have a copy of Code Complete 2nd Edition, which is excellent, but just wondering if there's any better, possibly more focused titles out there?

Thanks a lot!

Andy.

** UPDATE **

After a suggestion from JosephH, I'm going to mainly be working with c# and .Net (possibly silverlight!), if this helps anyone! :)

Comment: More focused on what aspects?

Comment: @Oded - Well, I guess that's the point, I'm not really sure what goes into commercial, long life code-bases and applications. :) Perhaps build tools, localisation, architcture, management of the code-base etc. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Working effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0131177052?ie=UTF8&tag=jjh-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=0131177052).

The title is slightly misleading - although it's a very good book at showing you ways to work with Legacy code, it's also good at showing you good and bad ways to do things, why it matters, and has a focus on producing testable code. (The author's definition of "Legacy code" is any code that doesn't have automated tests.) The examples are in C, C++ or Java.

(You might want to state what language and technologies you're working with to get more focussed answers.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll have to have a look into it! :)